# Finding a limit

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to check whether the limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ exists?

I proceed as follows:

$\vert \dfrac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\vert \leq \dfrac{x^2+y^2}{\vert(x^2+y^2)^2 \vert}=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2}$.

But this does not help me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write $a = x^2+y^2$ to simplify notation. Then use the Taylor expansion of $\cos$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\frac{2 \sin^2 \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, $$ as well as that for small $\theta$ $$\sin \theta \sim \theta. $$

Answer (score 2):

Using polar coordinates, and substituting $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, we have $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\lim_{r \to 0} \dfrac {1 - \cos(r^2)}{(r^2)^2} = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos(r^2)}{r^4}$$

You can use l'hopital, now, repeatedly (three times)..

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to find multivariable limits using polar coordinates? Substitute $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, where $r$ is the distance from the origin to the point $(x,y)$. Then $(x,y)$ approaching the origin is equivalent to $r$ approaching 0. In this way you can reduce the problem to a single variable limit problem, and use L'hôpital's rule for instance.